# lookup several values in a table and return the sum of those values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I'd like to lookup several values in a second table and add them up.
let me go into more detail

I have one table with numeric values and id's

```
 id||amount
>----------<
  3||12
 34||8
 16||40
678||34
```

the id's are unique

I now want to build a partial sum of the amount giving a list of id's

```
 list of ids|| sum
 >---------------------<
     3,34,16||60
     34,16  ||48
     678    ||34
```

I figured out how to to look up the value of one id using match and index.

```
=INDEX(Data.A1:D6;MATCH(results.A4;Data.A1:A6;0);2)
```

the numeric values table is in the sheet "Data" the sum shall be displayed in the sheet "results". Currently the cell "results.A4" contains only one id. How can I have that "results.A4" contains a list and return the sum of the looked up values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT with a SEARCH():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & DATA!$A$2:$A$5 & ",";"," & results!A2 & ","))*DATA!$B$2:$B$5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, one should add there may be no spaces in the list